# Why is my windows crashing while running android emulator on android studio

Tags: windows, android-studio

```
Windows version: Windows 11 10.0.22000 Build 22000
Processor   11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-11320H @ 3.20GHz, 3187 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
Total Physical Memory   15.8 GB
```

I used the latest emulator version.[image]

These crashes occur only when I try to run the android emulator.

```
Windows Logs :

Log Name:      Application
Source:        Windows Error Reporting
Date:          28-10-2022 13:21:36
Event ID:      1001
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      
Description:
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: BlueScreen
Response: Not available
```